# How to use Jquery autocomplete with the backend couchDb

Tags: jquery-ui, couchdb

So far I've used Jquery autocomplete for backend php. But I want to use jquery auto complete to fetch records from couchdb. Can anyone please help me.

Or is there any other way to achieve autocomplete with couchDB

Answer (score 0):

```
    function log( message ) { 
    $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
    $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
  }
  $("#search_name").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.couch.db("db1").view("Views/testPatients", {
            success: function(data) {
                response(data.rows);
            },
            error: function(status) {
                console.log(status);
            },
            key: request.term

        });
    },
    minLength: 3,
    focus: function(event, ui) {
      console.log(ui.item.key);
      $("#search_name").val(ui.item.key);
      return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      $("#search_name").val(ui.item.key);
      return false;
    },
    open: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
    },
    close: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
    }
  }).
  data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li></li>")
      .data("item.autocomplete", item)
      .append("<a>" + item.key + "</a>")
      .appendTo(ul);
  };
```